# how to include fontawesome and bootstrap inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Is there anyway to include font-awesome and bootstrap inline in the header of html page

I mean instead of using  we include the font-awesome and bootstrap in

the code i used " and it's not working probably and not showing the icons " is :

```html
    <style>
bootstrap.min.css
font-awesome.min.css
    </style>
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to [signup your email](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/) to use Font Awesome, then you get a js code to put in the head that looks like this

```html
<!-- Font Awesome JS -->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a0aac8df13.js"></script>
```

for Bootstrap put this in the head

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: yeah but i want to include it in the <style></style> tags in html to improve the speed .. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can include like

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boostrap.min.css">`

If you need to use your style sheet to various pages, then its always recommended to define a common style sheet in a separate file. A cascading style sheet file will have extension as .css and it will be included in HTML files using  tag.

font awesome cant be included in any other stylesheet and load using same link tag.

Comment: yeah but i want to include it in the <style></style> tags in html to improve the speed .. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

> yeah but i want to include it in the `style` tags in html to improve the speed .. is it possible ?

Your idea of inlining your css all in one style tag isn't a good idea.

You might think it will increase speed because you're not relying on an external link for the css to load, but you have to consider that these scripts are hosted on content distribution networks with very fast connections, and for the most part it's not worth the trouble to inline the entirety of your css in one file unless you're minifying that, javascript, and your html, similar to what google does.

So basically, if you did do it for a speed increase, you'd need to have a server task to do some sort of precompilation to inline it for you and minimize everything, so unless you're at the point that the bottleneck in your code is loading 2 css files, I wouldn't waste my time on something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the inclusion code in CSS (as the OP mentioned), use the [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) directive, like so:

```
<style>
    @import url("bootstrap.min.css");
    @import url("font-awesome.min.css");
</style>
```

Note, however, that this practice is not recommended and will actually *increase* load time.